# Moving average (and rolling mean) using `stats::filter`

Tags: r, time-series, moving-average

I am learning to calculate moving averages in R with this code:

```
x <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 10)

mn <- function(n) rep (1 / n, n)

y <- filter(x, mn(5))
```

When I plot only `mn(5)`, I see that 1/5 is repeated 5 times. My questions are:

1. Why using `filter(x, mn(5))` calculates the average of the five values?
2. What part of `x` is averaged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What part of `x` is averaged?

See `?filter` for argument `sides`. The default value `sides = 2` means "center". You probably want `sides = 1` to use past values only.

In general,

```
y <- filter(x, c(w1, w2, w3, w4, w5), sides = 1)
```

computes:

```
y[1:4] = NA
y[5] = w1 * x[5] + w2 * x[4] + w3 * x[3] + w4 * x[2] + w5 * x[1]
y[6] = w1 * x[6] + w2 * x[5] + w3 * x[4] + w4 * x[3] + w5 * x[2]
## and etc.
```

> Why using `filter(x, mn(5))` calculates the average of the five values?

In this particular case:

```
y <- filter(x, c(1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5), sides = 1)
```

computes:

```
y[1:4] = NA
y[5] = (x[5] + x[4] + x[3] + x[2] + x[1]) / 5 = mean(x[5:1])
y[6] = (x[6] + x[5] + x[4] + x[3] + x[2]) / 5 = mean(x[6:2])
## and etc.
```

which gives rolling mean.

---

**Remark:**

Moving average is much more general than rolling mean. Another way to compute simple rolling mean is

```
zoo::rollmean(x, k = 5, na.pad = TRUE, align = "right")
```

There is also an **R** package called **RcppRoll**.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** The mean is the average of the values so assuming x has 5 elements we can write the second line and that is the same as the third line and the fourth line so using coefficients of (1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5) in the sum is equivalent to taking the mean.

```
mean(x) 
= (x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5])/5
= x[1]/5 + x[2]/5 + x[3]/5 + x[4]/5 + x[5]/5
= sum(x * c(1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5))
```

**2)** Another way to understand this is to note that mean is linear.  That is if x and y are two vectors of the same length then mean(x+y) = mean(x) + mean(y) and if a is any scalar then mean(a * x) = a * mean(x).  Now it is known that any linear function that returns a scalar is representable as the inner product of some vector times the input.  That is there is a vector v such that

```
mean(x)
sum(v * x)
```

are equal for all x.  Now since it is true for all x it must be true for x <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0) so these are equal

```
mean(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
v[1] * x[1]
```

but the second line equals v[1] since x[1] is 1 and the mean of c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0) in the first line equals 1/5 and similarly for

```
mean(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0))
v[2] * x[2]
```

etc. so v must equal c(1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5, 1/5).